# Query example in pgrouting by PostGIS

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, for-loop

I found a query in the web which create catchments by pgrouting.
I tried the query several times and modified a bit. But it dosen´t work.
It alwys shows me the same error.

```
    DO $$
DECLARE
    c integer;
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
    CREATE TABLE tmp (
        agg_cost integer,
        geom geometry(MULTIPOLYGON, 4326)
    );

    FOR c IN SELECT agg_cost FROM temp1 GROUP BY agg_cost HAVING COUNT(1);
    3 ORDER BY 1 DESC LOOP
        RAISE INFO '%', c;
        INSERT INTO tmp (agg_cost, geom)
        SELECT
            c,
            ST_Multi(ST_SetSRID(pgr_pointsAsPolygon(
                'SELECT
                        temp1.id::integer,
                        ST_X(temp1.the_geom)::float AS x,
                        ST_Y(temp1.the_geom)::float AS y
                FROM temp1
                WHERE agg_cost = ' || c
            ), 4326));
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

the query is from the page:
https://www.zimmi.cz/posts/2017/routing-with-pgrouting-catchment-area-calculation/
and I got the error:

> ERROR:  missing "LOOP" at end of SQL expression
>   LINE 11: ...ELECT agg_cost FROM temp1 GROUP BY agg_cost HAVING COUNT(1);

Does someone know what I need to change?

Comment: remove the `;` behind `COUNT(1)`

Comment: I tried it at different places and i completly removed the ; but it doesen't work .. likw this HAVING COUNT(1) and < 3 ORDER BY 1 DESC LOOP, but than he is complaining about the '<'